# How can i download the files from s3 bucket to local directory using Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I currently confuse why my exec command for downloading the files from s3 to local directory, not working on laravel, however in AWS command line interface, the command that I created is downloading and working well. please see the reference that I attach below.

[image: AWS Command Interface]

I have here my sample code that I created on my public function

**Function:**

```
public function send_zip_files_to_store() {

    $source = 's3://compexp/11-10-2019/01790exp.zip';
    $destination = 'C:\xampp\htdocs';
    exec('aws cp sync ' . $source . ' ' . $destination);

}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/send_zip_files_to_store','DashController@send_zip_files_to_store')->name('send_zip_files_to_store');
```

Comment: Because your file is not http accessible. You can't execute S3 batch commands in laravel because it has no knowledge of it.

Comment: so what should i do to download the file to my project folder using laravel?